# Install Ruby Ubuntu With update-alternatives Command

Tags: server, ruby, rvm, update-alternatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No ruby alternatives on 11.04 / 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96424/no-ruby-alternatives-on-11-04-11-10)

I have 2 questions about ruby on ubuntu.

1. I've already install ruby1.8 and ruby1.9.1 on ubuntu lucid but when I run "update-alternatives --config ruby" on terminal then the output is "update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for ruby." How to fix this?
2. What's difference and advantages to install ruby on ubuntu by using RVM and update-alternatives?
   Sorry if my english's language is not good enough. :D
   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't know. Do Ruby support alternatives?
2. It depends on what you want to do.

If you want to develop applications, the RVM might be a good solution,depending on what you want to have. Then latest features might be ok and you can manage API changes in libraries.

If you want to administrate a web site, you do want to use software packed by Ubuntu/Debian, as they are stable and will not change the API "under your feets".

This was a large controversy between Debian packer and Ruby developers. Ruby developers didn't understood the problem for system administrators with fast development and changing API:s.